# How to set apk for both device and tablet versions in market

Tags: android

I have created application in android Sdk version 11(ie Android 3), and in manifist file i given minSdk version set to 4(ie Android 1.6). is this possible for , only one apk that should visible for both device and Tablet versions in android market. i already know that Android market supports muiltiple Apk's. But i dont know this case will work ?

Comment: your case will work fine... it will be available to both.

Comment: suppose i download apk and installed in 2.1 device.How it is work?

Comment: it will work, because we given minSdk is 4. so from 1.6 itself it will work.

Comment: But u are developed ur app on 3.suppose android:xlargeScreens="true" is available from 2.3.3 only but not for 2.1 here how the code will be work for 2.1

Comment: @Chiru it will work, because we not only given xlarge support, we also giving all different types of screen resolutions. it will work from 1.6 itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//if you put support screen in your manifest as xlarge is true it will work

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:xlargeScreens="true" 
                  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

[Link:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Comment: No, i dint put this support screen. Are you sure once we given this it will display in both the versions..??